# Android cash drawer commands

Tags: android, hardware

I've a cash drawer and I need to open it with command from an Android application. But I'm unable to read manual properly.

Here is a set of commands to open drawer. I am using following code from internet to achieve this. I'm receiving an error at the command set. Please can you guys suggest any code useful to achieve the cash drawer kick open functionality with press of a button? Also help me to read the manual.

```
 final byte[] openCD={27,112,0,60,120};
    String s=new String(openCD);
    commandSet+=s;
    return s;
```

Manual Sample

**Cash drawer control command**

> ESC p m n1 n2 Generate pulse n1 n2 
>   rawer control command 
>   ASCII ESC p  m Decimal 27 112 m 
>   Format 
>   n1 n2 Hexadecimal 1B 70  m n1 n2

Cash drawer is attached to the Android device through a cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this thing

```
String file= "/sys/class/gpio/gpio14/value";


writeToFile(file,"1");

writeToFile(file,"0");




public static void writeToFile(String fileName, String data){

    File file = new File("/sys/class/gpio/gpio14/value");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try{
        outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte [] bytes = data.getBytes();
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

1 is for opening drawer and 0 is for closing. Place code on button click